# AutoHotKey - Send singular key press on program launch

Tags: autohotkey

I'd like to have the F11 key pressed as soon as the program opens without having to press any hotkeys or such, basically automatic key press on launch. Here is my code:

```
; This section fullscreens XENIA on Play
#SingleInstance, Force

numpad0::
IfWinExist, ahk_class XeniaWindowClass ahk_exe xenia.exe
{
    WinActivate, ahk_class XeniaWindowClass
    #IfWinActive, ahk_class XeniaWindowClass
    {
        Send, {F11}
    }
}
return
```

Any help appreicated, thank you!

Comment: Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? Please [edit] these details in or we may not be able to help.

Comment: See my answer to your previous post.

Comment: Sure, since my program starts windowed by default and it's locked to that I want my code to send F11 (which fullscreens the program) to the program as soon as it's started up and detected so that it fullscreens. As you see in my code now I've included numpad0:: to test if my code, which it does, but I don't want to be pressing any keys and I want all this to be automatically done for me on launch.

Comment: Have a look at [`WinWait`](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinWait.htm) and [`WinWaitClose`](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinWaitClose.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I see.  Then this is how you do it.  You run the function and you can also call it by pressing `numpad0` (but, you have to launch this script after running the program, or see my answer on previous post):

```
; This section fullscreens XENIA on Play
#Persistent
#SingleInstance, Force

GoSub, DoIt
return

numpad0::
GoSub, DoIt
return

DoIt:
IfWinExist, ahk_class XeniaWindowClass ahk_exe xenia.exe
{
    WinActivate, ahk_class XeniaWindowClass
    #IfWinActive, ahk_class XeniaWindowClass
    {
        Send, {F11}
    }
}
return
```

Hth, lmk . . .

Comment: @IanB I have also elaborated an answer on your other post.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this?

```
#Persistent
SetTimer, XeniaWatcher

XeniaWatcher() {
    WinWaitActive, ahk_class XeniaWindowClass
    Send, {F11}
    WinWaitNotActive, ahk_class XeniaWindowClass
}
```

Or this?

```
#Persistent
SetTimer, XeniaWatcher

XeniaWatcher() {
    WinWaitActive, ahk_class XeniaWindowClass
    Send, {F11}
    WinWaitClose, ahk_class XeniaWindowClass
}
```

Comment: Your AHK seems to be outdated then.

Answer (score 0):

```
; This section fullscreens XENIA on Play
#SingleInstance, Force
SetInterval, check, 200 ; check every 200ms
sentB4:=0

check:
If ( (WinExist("ahk_class XeniaWindowClass")) && (WinExist("ahk_exe xenia.exe")) ) {
    If (sentB4 == 0) {
        WinActivate, ahk_class XeniaWindowClass
        If ( WinActive("ahk_class XeniaWindowClass") ) {
            send, {F11} ; send desired key (fullscreen in this case)
            sentB4:=1 ; update status
        }
    }
} else {
    sentB4:=0 ; reset status
}
return
```

I updated your outdated IfWinExist functions because they were deprecated, read comments for more info

```
numpad0::
    gosub, check
    return
```

Add that for manual triggering as well...